# JSON export data from database?

Tags: java, database, json, spring-mvc

Hi, I am working on web applications.I have a query.How can I export data from database to JSON using spring,I am unable to understand.Please help me to resolve this.

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: without posting what you can't understand, how we know that?

Comment: 1) Extract the data.  2) Encode it as JSON.

Comment: for a start you might want to post how you can retrieve some data from your database

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody MyObj getJSON() {
    MyObj obj = new MyObj();

    return obj;
```

}

Put `jackson` in your classpath and `@ResponseBody` annotation in controller method handler.

Also enable `mvc:annotation-driven` in your servlet config.

In this case MyObj will be serialized in JSON format.

Comment: could you please tel me hwo to do with xml

Comment: Take a look at this simple example: http://springinpractice.com/2012/02/22/supporting-xml-and-json-web-service-endpoints-in-spring-3-1-using-responsebody

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following links for database and JSON examples.

1. [Spring MVC JDBC Example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-jdbc-example/).
2. [Spring MVC and JSON](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/)